# Multiplying two complex SeriesLists by a specific node

Tags: graphite

Let's say I have 4 different Serieslists:

`foo.total`

`foo.succesful`

`bar.total`

`bar.succesful`

I have generated a complex graphite query for both of them, so it goes like
`function1(function2(foo.total))`

`function3(function4(foo.succesful))`

I want to multiply these by each other. Well, that's not very difficult:
`multiplySeries(function1(function2(foo.total)),function3(function4(foo.succesful)))`

This draws one graph and works as intended.
The problem I am facing when trying to wildcard the foo-part, so I can do *.total. In this case I want to draw 2 graphs, because there are 2 wildcarded variables.

So my question is, how can I generalize the above query to not only work with `foo` but with n number of variables?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of template function, the only one graphite provides is [`applyByNode`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.applyByNode) and it should be sufficient in your case:

```
applyByNode(
    *.{total,succesful},
    'multiplySeries(f1(f2(%.total)), f3(f4(%.succesful)))',
    '% some line'
)
```